# javaScript RegExp the second index

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the second ".at"'index in "cat, bat, sat, fat", the program is:

```
var text = "cat, bat, sat, fat";
var pattern = /.at/g;
var matches = pattern.exec(text);
var num = 2;
var i = 0;
while(pattern.test(text)){
  if(++i == num){
    alert(matches.index);
    break;
  }
  matches = pattern.exec(text);
}
```

The right index should be 5, but why I get 10, please?

-_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you're using the same regex for both `.test()` and `.exec()` and expecting the state to not be affected, but `lastIndex` is advanced by the `.test()` so it's not correct when the next `.exec()` happens.  To eliminate that issue, you can remove the `.test()` and then it works (and is more efficient):

```
var text = "cat, bat, sat, fat";
var pattern = /.at/g;
var num = 2, i = 0, matches;
while(matches = pattern.exec(text)){
  if(++i == num){
    alert(matches.index);
    break;
  }
}​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rbWQj/

Answer (score 1):

When repeatedly calling `exec` or `test` on a global regexp pattern, the starting position of the next search is stored in the regexp objects `lastIndex` property. Each call to either `test` or `exec` advances the `lastIndex` property. With that in mind let's see what your code is doing:

```
var text = "cat, bat, sat, fat";
var pattern = /.at/g;
var matches = pattern.exec(text); //goes over the first match at 0, lastIndex=3
var num = 2;
var i = 0;
while(pattern.test(text)){
  //first iteration: lastIndex=8 not 3, match at 5
  //second iteration: lastIndex=18, match at 15
  if(++i == num){
    //matches still has the match from 10
    alert(matches.index); //returns 10
    break;
  }
  matches = pattern.exec(text);
  //first iteration: lastIndex=13, match at 10
}
```

So yeah, using both test and exec in the code is throwing off the starting index of the next search.